# Does a Sri Lankan need a transit visa for Malaysia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan, travelling to Brunei from Colombo via Malaysia by Malaysian Airlines. I have a 6-hour layover in Kuala Lumpur. Do I need a transit visa?